# users change their passwords

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, password

how can i let users change their passwords on windows 2003 and 2008 file servers through the network?

Comment: Are the servers and workstations in a Windows domain?

Answer (score 2):

If they're in an AD domain (I sure hope that they are), then all they have to do is hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete and then click "change password". If your users aren't on the domain, then I believe you may just need to allow users to RDP to the servers in question and then change their password that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Active Directory:
If you are running Exchange, they can use OWA to change passwords.
Why can't they use Ctrl-Alt-Del?  Are they Macs?  I have my Mac users use OWA.
Another option is to set the expiration interval,  they should get a prompt to change their password, and the prompt will have a button to change it...